# PDO select query and then insert from the result data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've many data that i want to insert from 1 table to another table using select query and then insert the result. i follow some people method, I did it, but i get an error, it's about **parameter**

the select data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_barang] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [barang] => Flashdisk
            [1] => Flashdisk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_barang] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [barang] => OTG
            [1] => OTG
        )
)
```

then the skript ( i just following some people method ):

```
$kolomtable = array('ProductID','Product');

    function placeholders($text, $count=0, $separator=","){
        $result = array();
        if($count > 0){
            for($x=0; $x<$count; $x++){
                $result[] = $text;
            }
        }

        return implode($separator, $result);
    }

    $insert_values = array();
    foreach($data as $item){
        foreach($item as $key => $value){
            $question_marks[] = '('  . placeholders('?', sizeof($value)) . ')';
            $insert_values = array_merge($insert_values, array_values($value));
        }
    }

    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO `stock product all list` (" . implode(",", $kolomtable ) . ") VALUES " .
           implode(',', $question_marks);

    $stmt = $connect->prepare ($sqlinsert);
    $stmt->execute($insert_values);
```

but i get an error. i have a weakness with array, need your help guys.. thanks.

Comment: I don't follow your but maybe you can just a single `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and avoid some of the heavy lifting.

Comment: I would strongly recommend changing your table names as `stock product all list` may cause all sorts of problems.